# For Loop on item: 'TELLER' is not a cursor

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have the following cursor:

```
FUNCTION managers_meerdere_depart RETURN t_managers_table_type AS
    CURSOR manager_ids IS SELECT manager_id, count(manager_id) AS teller FROM departments
    WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY manager_id;
```

When I try to iterate over the counter (teller),

```
    FOR i IN teller LOOP <----- 
      SELECT d.department_id
      INTO v_dep_id
      FROM EMPLOYEES e
      JOIN DEPARTMENTS d ON e.employee_id = d.manager_id
      WHERE employee_id = manager_id_rec.manager_id;
      v_dep_ids(i) := v_dep_id;  
    END LOOP;
```

it gives me the following error:

> Error(84,33): PLS-00456: item 'TELLER' is not a cursor

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use teller instead of counter:

`FOR manager_id_rec IN manager_ids LOOP
  IF (manager_id_rec.teller> 1) THEN
    SELECT first_name, last_name
    INTO v_first_name, v_last_name
    FROM employees
    WHERE employee_id = manager_id_rec.manager_id;`

because you give the `count(manager_id)` an alias which is `teller`

Comment: My apologies. I translated teller (dutch for counter) to counter in my question. I've updated my question. Can  you please check again

Comment: you should iterate over cursor name and not a column.
'for i in manager_ids'

Comment: It should be the following: `FOR i IN 0..manager_id_rec.teller LOOP`

Comment: no it shouldn't be that way since you are browsing records that are given by the cursor, you should use only the name of the cursor in your for loop.
`FOR i IN manager_ids`

Comment: yes, my outer loop is for the name of the cursor. But i needed a nested loop where my inner loop needs to use the counter (teller)

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. How did you make it work?